# Adding the last row number to an excel formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

having a bit of a problem and not sure how possible this is. I'm trying to get the last row number (not count) in a column and then use that number in a formula. The reference would be in the SUMIF(R[5] and R[6] statements. I want to change the R to reflect whatever the last row is.

Here is what I have and while it returns the row number I need I can't figure out how to define or use it in the formula. I'm not sure if this is even the best way to do it.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub test()
    Dim lrow As Long

    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    Selection.Value = ActiveCell.Row - 1

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(RC[-6]="""",if(RC[-8]=R[-1]C[-8],R[-1]C,SUMIF(R[5]C[-8]:R[6]C[-8],RC[-8],R[5]C[-11]:R[6]C[-11])),"""")"
End Sub
```

EDIT:
So the idea is to get the formula to look at the column labeled RD/SFC and anything that matches, for example if in RD/SFC row match 6605 we then add everything in the columns Est FNL sales to the end of the row and same for the $Ret Cost column. Currently trying to do that through the formula and put it in Column O.

Hope that helps explain a little bit more

[image]

Comment: I find it easier to set up formulas in VBA by removing the R1C1 (i.e. ActiveCell.Formula = ) and then pasting what you see in the formula bar in the worksheet into the line of code. All of those Rs, and Cs and RCs personally drive me up the wall. It also makes it much easier to do what your trying to do here. You would simply replace the number corresponding to the last row in your formula with your variable lrow.

Comment: this is normally what I do but the last row changes depending on which spreadsheet we are working on. To add another complicated layer to this is the fact that there is a break in the spreadsheet (Row of blank cells) between the two data sets. so all formula references to R[5] are one set (one last row reference) and R[6] is the other set (second last row reference).

Comment: Is 6605 unique to the first group, or does it appear down the list in other groups?

Comment: Not unique there could be any number of combinations. usually there are sets/groups though which we are adding together.

Comment: Could you run a formulatext() on O3...it would be helpful to see what's in there.

Comment: Also, as I'm looking at this, I'm thinking that Power Query would probably provide a good solution for your problem.

Comment: The formula text is as follows, but it isn't accounting for last row which is what I need it to do        
     `IF(I2="",IF(G2=G1,O1,SUMIF(G123:G1385,G2,D123:D1385)),"") `

Answer (score 1):

may this help:

```
'To get the last row with data in a given column
Public Function lastRowInOneColumn(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal givenCol As Long) As Long

With ws
    lastRowInOneColumn = .Cells(.Rows.count, givenCol).End(xlUp).Row
End With

End Function
```